# Problem when installing fredhopper in a linux environment

Tags: smarttarget, installation, linux

I'm trying to setup Fredhopper in my linux server. I set my java home, created a fredhopper user, as specified in the documentation.

However, when I want to start the deployment agent, i get the following error

Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
We cannot execute /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java

But, the java path is correct, and the user has execute rights on the java program, so I'm wondering what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

After some trial and error, it seems to be working when I install java 1.7 on my linux machine, instead of java 1.8.
The Fredhopper documentation specifies that the version I wanted to install requires java 1.7 or later, but apparently, running it with java 1.8 gives issues.